# Citroen C4 2.0 HDI 2005, Lighting in ac controls and headlight adjustment not working

Tags: ac, citroen, citroen-c4

Roughly a week ago the lighting in the AC controls and the headlight adjustment stopped working so now its impossible to adjust it at night. It all works... its just the lighting. well the headlight adjustment doesnt work at all and theyre stuck in the lowest position. could it just be a fuse or?

Thanks in advance.

Kristoffer

Answer (score 2):

If they both stopped working at the same time, it could be a fuse or a loose electrical connection at the dimmer switch.

If they stopped working separately, it could be as simple as a burnt out bulb in your AC control panel, and the switch went bad separately. The bulbs are inexpensive to replace, but those AC control panels can often be a pain to remove. Since they sit in the center of the vehicle, some vehicles have the screws for them hidden by other trim pieces and you end-up disassembling half the cabin just to get to 2 to 4 screws. :( Find a maintenance manual for your vehicle, it will tell you how to remove the AC control panel.